# How to list the collections of all databases when i am logged in as admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My goal is to list all Databases with their collections. Same as you login as user admin into robo3T for instance.

There is no problem to use the two commands below. But when I use the listCollections command I just receive the collections of the admin database. But unfortunatley not from all databases of admin user.

```
let db =  client.db('admin').admin();
db.command({listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true}, (err, dbs)=>{});
db.command({listCollections: 1, nameOnly: true}, (err, collections)=>{});
```

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: adminDb.command({listCollections: 1, nameOnly: true}, (err, collections)=>{}); this should say everything you are accessing the collections of the `adminDb` if you want to get the other db collections you will need to establish a new connection for each

Comment: hm.. As admin I have the rights to list all databases but not their collections? doesn´t make sence for me.

Comment: You can `use dbName` and then list collections

Comment: nope, seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not need an admin command.

Correct:

let db =  client.db('dbName').<strike>admin()</strike>;